# Dual Free Panes with HTML/CSS/Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to mimic the functionality of Excel's freeze panes feature.

See example picture of what I'm trying to achieve:![example of what I'm talking about]
[image]

I have already attempted this solution (for Div 2) [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pDhmy/4/)
Basically it uses the following code to keep an absolute positioned element at the top of the div while scrolling.

From JSFiddle link above:

```
$('.mega').on('scroll',function(){$('.header').css('top',$(this).scrollTop());});
```

However, when I scrolled, the header would be very choppy and jump around. It wasn't fixed to the top of Div2, sometimes it would scroll down and jump back up to the top. I spent a bunch of time on this solution without success.

I've done extensive searching, but could not find anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I can't be the first one with this requirement for a project.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://datatables.net/

Comment: @epascarello Because that plug-in seems like overkill since I only need one part of it's functionality. Don't wanna manage another plugin that relies on jQuery.

Comment: But you are using jQuery above. And it is not an easy thing you are trying to do. Have fun. :)

Comment: @epascarello You are correct, I am using jQuery... what I meant was that adding another plugin that relies on jQuery isn't in my best interest as I already have a few for this project. This makes it difficult to ever upgrade jQuery when you have a bunch of plug-ins that rely on it. I did finally figure it out -- see solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution... it's not terrible, but it gets the job done for my requirements.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/josip0423/Mtn73/)

Here's the magic.

```
$('#jqInnerDivRight').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#jqInnerDivLeft').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    $('#jqRightHeader').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});
```